# Nearest Neighbour Index (NNI): how to compare values & in depth explanation of how to calculate expected mean distance

Tags: spatial-statistics, spatial-cluster

I have two questions regarding the ‘Nearest Neighbour Index (NNI)’, sometimes also referred to as ‘Nearest Neighbour Analysis (NNA)’:

1. I have calculated the ‘Nearest Neighbour Index’ for 4 different point patterns within the same study area (different types of buildings with and without solar panels; I want to check if neighbours are more likely to install solar panels). Now I wish to compare the different indexes. Is there a test that I can perform that tells me if the difference between the various ‘Nearest Neighbour Indexes’ is significant? I get the following indexes: 0.39, 0.45, 0.51, 0.62
2. I understand that the Expected mean distance is calculated as follows: 0.5 * Square root of A/n (A: Study Area; n = number of points) but I do not understand this formula in depth. Why do we need to calculate the square root of the density and then divide 0.5 by this result?